# rails tutorial 2nd edition. chapter 6.3.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, railstutorial.org

I hope someone can help. I am going through Michael Hartl's rails tutorial book and am stuck on [chapter 6.3.4](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-users#sec-has_secure_password). I am trying to get all the tests to validate and I keep getting several errors. I have posted the error messages and also my user.rb and user_spec.rb file for reference.
Hopefully someone can see where I am going wrong. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Errors**

```
Failures:

  1) when email address is already taken
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31muser_with_same_email = @user.dup←[0m
     ←[31mTypeError:←[0m
       ←[31mcan't dup NilClass←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:69:in `dup'←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:69:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required
)>'←[0m

  2) when password is not present
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mbefore { @user.password = @user.password_confi
rmation = " " }←[0m
     ←[31mNoMethodError:←[0m
       ←[31mundefined method `password_confirmation=' for nil:NilClass←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:78:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required
)>'←[0m

  3) when password doesn't match confirmation
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mbefore { @user.password_confirmation = "mismat
ch" }←[0m
     ←[31mNoMethodError:←[0m
       ←[31mundefined method `password_confirmation=' for nil:NilClass←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:83:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required
)>'←[0m

  4) when password confirmation is nil
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mbefore { @user.password_confirmation = nil }←[
0m
     ←[31mNoMethodError:←[0m
       ←[31mundefined method `password_confirmation=' for nil:NilClass←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:88:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required
)>'←[0m

  5) with a password that's too short
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mbefore { @user.password = @user.password_confi
rmation = "a" * 5 }←[0m
     ←[31mNoMethodError:←[0m
       ←[31mundefined method `password_confirmation=' for nil:NilClass←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:93:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required
)>'←[0m

  6) return value of authticate method with valid password
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mbefore { @user.save }←[0m
     ←[31mNoMethodError:←[0m
       ←[31mundefined method `save' for nil:NilClass←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:98:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required
)>'←[0m

  7) return value of authticate method with invalid password
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mbefore { @user.save }←[0m
     ←[31mNoMethodError:←[0m
       ←[31mundefined method `save' for nil:NilClass←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:98:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required
)>'←[0m
```

**user.rb file**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password

  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }

 validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
 VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
 validates :email,  presence: true,
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, 
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
 validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
 validates :password_confirmation, presence: true                   
end
```

user_spec.rb

require 'spec_helper'

```
describe User do

    before do
        @user = User.new(   name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", 
                            password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
    end 

    subject { @user }

        it { should respond_to(:name) }
        it { should respond_to(:email) }
        it { should respond_to(:password_digest) }
        it { should respond_to(:password) }
        it { should respond_to(:password_confirmation) }

        it { should be_valid }

        it { should respond_to(:authenticate) }

        describe "when name is not present" do
            before { @user.name = " " }
            it { should_not be_valid }
        end 

        describe "when email is not present" do
            before { @user.email = " " }
            it { should_not be_valid }
        end 

        describe "when name is too long" do
            before { @user.name = "a" * 51 }
            it { should_not be_valid }
        end

        describe "when email format is invalid" do
            it "should be invalid" do
                addresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example.user@foo.
                                foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
                addresses.each do |invalid_address|
                    @user.email = invalid_address
                    @user.should_not be_valid
                end
            end
        end

        describe "when email format is valid" do
            it "should be valid" do
                addresses = %w[user@foo.COM A_US-ER@f.b.org frst.lst@foo.jp a+b@baz.cn]
                addresses.each do |valid_address|
                    @user.email = valid_address
                    @user.should be_valid
        end 

        describe "when email address is already taken" do
            before do
                user_with_same_email = @user.dup
                user_with_same_email.email = @user.email.upcase
                user_with_same_email.save
        end

            it { should_not be_valid }
        end

        describe "when password is not present" do
            before { @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = " " }
            it { should_not be_valid }
        end

        describe "when password doesn't match confirmation" do
            before { @user.password_confirmation = "mismatch" }
            it { should_not be_valid }
        end 

        describe "when password confirmation is nil" do
            before { @user.password_confirmation = nil }
            it { should_not be_valid }
        end

        describe "with a password that's too short" do
            before { @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = "a" * 5 }
            it { should be_invalid }
        end

        describe "return value of authticate method" do
            before { @user.save }
            let(:found_user) { user.find_by_email(@user.email) }

            describe "with valid password" do
                it { should == found_user.authenticate(@user.password) }
        end

        describe "with invalid password" do
            let(:user_for_invalid_password) { found_user.authenticate("invalid") }
            specify { user_for_invalid_password.should be_false }
        end

        end             
    end
end
```

end

Comment: Hint: Remove those <-[31m to understand more about error msgs: http://linksxplored.blogspot.com/2013/04/rspec-test-gives-32m0m32m0m32m0m32m-in.html

Answer (score 0):

In your user.rb, your validates have incorrect syntax.

EDIT - Also, check his code directly against yours. He has a [git repository here](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_2nd_ed).

- It looks like you also have some different differences in your user_spec compared to his.

Instead of this:

```
validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email,  presence: true,
                   format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, 
                   uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
```

Do this:

```
validates :name, :presence => true, 
                 :length => { :maximum => 50 }

VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

validates :email,  :presence => true,
                   :format => { :with => VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, 
                   :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }

validates :password, :presence => true, 
                     :length => { :minimum => 6 }

validates :password_confirmation, :presence => true
```

Comment: Hi adback, I have made the amendments to the user.rb file and this is still giving me the same error messages

Comment: Check my edit. I provided a link to the source code to compare yours against.

Comment: hi adback, I have reviewed the code from github and have modified the user_spec.rb file and this has provided me with a solution to the problem.